# Contains at least a count of different character in a set

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Assume that, I have a character set like this:

```
['a','b','c','x','y','z']
```

I want to build a regular expression which matches a certain number of these characters (for example 3).

Here are some examples of it:

- `ab` - no match
- `xy` - no match
- `abt` - no match
- `aaa` - no match
- `abc` - match
- `yaz` - match
- `yazx` - match
- `ytaz` - match

Can this be accomplished with a regular expression?

Comment: So you would match `aaaa` all day long then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be a pattern like this:

```
(.*[abcxyz]){3}
```

This will match zero or more of any character, followed by one of `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y`, or `z`, all of which must appear at least 3 times in the subject string.

To match only strings that contain *different* letters, you could use a negative lookahead (`(?!…)`) and a backreference (`\N`):

```
(.*([abcxyz])(?!.*\2)){3}
```

This will match zero or more of any character, followed by one of `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y`, or `z`, as long as another instance of that character does not appear later in the string (i.e. it will match the last instance of that character in the string), all of which must appear at least 3 times in the subject string.

Of course, you can change the `{3}` to anything you like, but note that will not work if you need to specify a *maximum* number of times these characters can appear in your string, only the minimum.

Comment: 'abt - mismatch' would match your regex.

Comment: @user17130 `abt` would not match, but the full string `abt - mismatch` would because of the `a` and `c` in `mismatch`. OP hasn't specified if all three characters need to appear in the same word or not.

Comment: This will also match aaa . I was meaning when i said `at least`, it was at least 3 different character. aaa contains only one.

Comment: Will this work if the number is increased `(.*([abcxyz])(?!.*\2)){5} ?`

Comment: Updated version seems working properly. @sln The example that you gave also seems working. I took minus rep, but I guess, it worth :)

Comment: @sln Yeah it's pretty flexible. It would even work if you needed to match specific 'phrases', e.g. `(.*(foo|bar|baz|qux)(?!.*\2)){3}` Will match a string that contains three or more of those 'phrases'.

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g ! I'm going to have to go in the Perl debugger and see how this works.

Comment: @AhmetDAL There are a *lot* of really terrible questions in the `regex` tag. To avoid downvotes in the future, be sure to include 1) a *very clear* description of the requirements including positive and negative examples 2) what language / platform you're using or any other constraints you have—every regex engine has different limitations—and 3) what you've tried so far and why it didn't work.

Comment: Amazingly, in Perl (with: using re 'debug';) if the lazy quantifier is used `.*?` it executes using 1/3 the instructions than with greedy. Using lazy though biases the search from the beginning, it matches correctly every time, but sometimes match with shorter length. I still can't follow how its doing it though.

Comment: @p.s.w.g What if I want to make the characters or phrases in my set as a block. I mean there will be no other character which is not in my set in matched part. For example;`abtx` won't be matching but `abxt` will be matching. Is that possible?

Comment: @AhmetDAL Yeah, that's pretty straight forward. Remove the leading `.*` to match any sequence of *n* characters in that set that doesn't repeat (would match `abax` but not `abaax`). Or replace the leading `.` with the acceptable set of characters you want to allow between matching characters, e.g. `([abcxyz]*([abcxyz])(?!.*\2)){3}`, to match `abaax` too.